# Where does JRebel store credentials on Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, credentials, jrebel

Where does JRebel store credentials on Mac?

For example - It stores the credentials in registry on Windows.

I am trying to use another free license after my previous license expired.

Comment: Ask from support@zeroturnaround.com for a prolonged license. Otherwise what you're trying to do is to crack the software - not good.

Answer (score 0):

The location is:

> /Users//.jrebel